# use route FOSJSRoutingBundle in javascript file returns error

Tags: javascript, symfony, bundle, symfony-3.4, fosjsroutingbundle

I am working on symfony project (version 3.4) I would like to access to a route from javacsript file. I have seen on symfony documentation that I can use FOSJsRoutingBundle. I have followed the doc to install it and configure it but when I try to access to my website, I get this error :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. which is related to this line added to my js file :

import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

this is what I get in dev.log file :

```
[2018-11-30 22:50:53] request.INFO: Matched route "ens_category_page". {"route":"ens_category_page","route_parameters":{"_controller":"JobeetBundle\\Controller\\CategoryController::indexAction","_route":"ens_category_page"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8888/jobeet/web/app_dev.php/categories","method":"GET"} []
```

[2018-11-30 22:50:53] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2018-11-30 22:50:54] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2 FROM category t0 [] []
[2018-11-30 22:50:55] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_js_routing_js". {"route":"fos_js_routing_js","route_parameters":{"_controller":"fos_js_routing.controller:indexAction","_format":"js","_route":"fos_js_routing_js"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8888/jobeet/web/app_dev.php/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData","method":"GET"} []
[2018-11-30 22:50:56] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"b81260","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8888/jobeet/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/b81260","method":"GET"} []

thanks in advance for your response.[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the unexpected identifier? Did you copy the full error message?

Instead of importing Routing in your js file, can you try to load fos in your layout as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)?

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

Comment: the error refers to the line I have specified on my post, I have edited my post to send a picture. I have added these lines to my layout , that's what I have done but it is not working